# Image Sequence input missing frames FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, windows

Is it possible for ffmpeg to parse an input image sequence with missing frames? I was hoping to interpolate them or create a variable framerate(or a CCFR duplicate frame) video while having the numbering of the files match the frame in the video they correspond to.
I haven't been able to find an answer to this.

With my attempts, when it reaches a missing frame, the file ends and encode finishes.

Is it also possible to use a regex to match the various naming and padding of the images in the sequence? I haven't been able to without renaming the files first.
These are a few of the example file names in one sequence

```
00000XTR_00000_BURST20190321113858.jpg
00026IMG_00026_BURST20190321113858_COVER.jpg
00143IMG_00143_BURST20190321113858.jpg
00280XTR_00280_BURST20190321113858.jpg
```

I'm on windows but using wildcard hasn't worked in the filename. I've tried something like this with no luck

```
%05IMG_%05_BURST20190321113858*.jpg
```

Comment: Use the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer) and add duration directives.